# JAVA Action Performed not working

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, buttonclick

I'm creating buttons by this for, and when i click him.. not happening anything... When i click in btn, not calling the function btnActionPerformed... how to make it work?

```
private void btButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    // TODO add your handling code here
    int[] ret = new int[SQL.freetables().size()];
    Iterator<Integer> iterator = SQL.freetables().iterator();
    for (int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++)
    {
    ret[i] = iterator.next().intValue();
    int num=SQL.freetables().size() + 1;
    this.btn = new JButton();
    this.btn.setText("" + ret[i]);
    this.btn.setSize(60,20);
    int x = 100+(80*i);
    this.btn.setLocation(x, 140);
    this.btn.setVisible(true);
    this.add(btn);     
   // }

    }
    this.revalidate();
    this.repaint();
}          

private void btnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    System.out.print("\b Test: " + btn.getText());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to register to `actionPreformed`

```
this.btn.addActionListener(this);
```

your code should be:

```
bt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
       // TODO add your handling code here
       int[] ret = new int[SQL.freetables().size()];
       Iterator<Integer> iterator = SQL.freetables().iterator();
       for (int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++)
       {
          ret[i] = iterator.next().intValue();
          int num=SQL.freetables().size() + 1;
          this.btn = new JButton();
          this.btn.setText("" + ret[i]);
          this.btn.setSize(60,20);
          int x = 100+(80*i);
          this.btn.setLocation(x, 140);
          this.btn.setVisible(true);
          this.add(btn);   
          btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) { 
               // TODO add your handling code here:
               System.out.print("\b Test: " + btn.getText());
             } 
          }

          this.revalidate();
          this.repaint();
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: It work... :).. But i have one more question, if i put the ActionPerformed inside of for, when i got Text of the btn, will ever the last number of free table... if i got two free tables, 1 and 3 when i click, everytime i will got the "3"... So, its the cause of i tried to put out of for loop...

Answer (score 3):

You have to implement the `ActionListener` interface.  Neither of these methods match the required signature that I can see.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html

The method is `actionPerformed`.  The listener has to be attached to the `JButton`.  I see neither one in your code.

You appear to be in dire need of a [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

Comment: Hmmm... Thank you i will see this tutorial to learn a little more of swing... I was working in Android, so i didnt need swing style, but now i'm sure that the Layout Styles are different.. And will read about swing...